# jQuery autocomplete and back button behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history

I'm using the awesome [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete). However I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to understanding browser behaviour and Ajax, so I have a question.

This is the sequence of events:

1. User types 'fish' into text box
2. User chooses book title from list of autocomplete options - Fish Farming, Fish Frying, etc
3. HTML loads on page (as ajax) - 'click here for Fish Farming'
4. User clicks on link and loads Fish Farming page
5. User decides Fish Farming isn't for them, clicks on 'back' button - and returns to an empty page!

How can I change this so that when the user returns to the home page, they see the Fish Farming html - the page they were just looking at?

This is my autocomplete code:

```
    // Autocomplete listener.
    $("#q").catcomplete({
            source: "/book_results",
            select: function(event,ui) {
                $('#book_results').html(load_img);
                if (ui.item.category=="Books") { 
                    $.bbq.removeState();
                    var paramsObj = { 'b' : ui.item.id };
                    $.bbq.pushState( paramsObj );
                    get_books(null, null, null, ui.item.id);
                } else {
                    $.bbq.removeState();
                    var paramsObj = { 's' : ui.item.id };
                    $.bbq.pushState( paramsObj );
                    get_books(null, ui.item.id, null);
                }
            }
    });
```

As you can see, I'm already using the [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to update the URL fragment when the user chooses something from autocomplete, just because it seemed like a good idea.

So I have my `book_id` set in the hash - but how can I  ensure that the relevant HTML loads when the user clicks Back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the user makes choices append anchors to URI or session state.

Make new events for the back and forward buttons and traverse the lists accordingly.

Comment: "As the user makes choices..." - I'm doing this with the BBQ plugin already, as per question. 
"Make new events..." - please could you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: I was explaining how to implement the BBQ plugin. You might want to check over the [BBQ example docs](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-jquery-ui-tabs/) more thoroughly, I not familiar with but it looks live you are saving the states without retrieving them.